# How to assign unit quantities for datagrid cell

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

```
public class DataGridLayer
    {
        public double Layerdepth { get; set; }  //  (m)
        public double Anndiameter { get; set; } // (inches)
        public double Layergradient { get; set; }   //(k/m)
        public double Formationconductivity { get; set; }   //(W/m/k)
        public double Formationcapacity { get; set; }   //(j/kg/k)
        public double Ftiondensity { get; set; }    //(kg/m3)

    }
```

The above class is the datagrid layers. 
I want to make sure the entered values in the datagrid cell are in `(m),(inches),(k/m),(W/m/k),(j/kg/k),(kg/m3)` . Is there a method to do this?

Comment: You can't assign units to datagrid cells. Btw what do you mean by entering values with respect to the units?

Comment: @lazyberezovsky: updated my question.Sorry for the mistake.

Comment: Suppose I'm entering number `5` is it `kg` or `inches`?

Comment: @ lazyberezovsky: The First cell value must be in (m), second in (inches) etc..If u enter `5` for the first cell then it should be in meters.

Comment: @linguni yes, but you are entering abstract numbers

Comment: @ lazyberezovsky: you mean by default it should be ok??

Comment: sure. You don't have any 'units' for cells in Excel

Comment: @lazyberezovsky: Actually, I take values from the datagrid and perform some calculation. How do i know whether it's in m or in inches when i do the calculation??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no 'units' for cells in the box. But you have several options to provide units:

1. Display units name in the header of column `Anndiameter (inches)`. Thus all entered values will be treated as inches.
2. Add column to the right side of values column. Fill it with combobox cells, which will allow to select unit for value.
3. Create your own datagrid cell, which will provide same functionality, as option 2.